# Cloudformation: Error: Member must have length less than or equal to 20

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I'm using this CloudFormation template to create a Cognito User Pool:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Template creates AWS Cognito UserPool.",
    "Resources": {
        "CognitoUserPool": {
            "Type": "AWS::Cognito::UserPool",
            "Properties": {
                "Policies": {
                    "PasswordPolicy": {
                        "MinimumLength": 8,
                        "RequireUppercase": true,
                        "RequireLowercase": true,
                        "RequireNumbers": true,
                        "RequireSymbols": true
                    }
                },
                "Schema": [
                    {
                        "Name": "sub",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": false,
                        "Required": true,
                        "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                            "MinLength": "1",
                            "MaxLength": "2048"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "name",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false,
                        "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                            "MinLength": "0",
                            "MaxLength": "2048"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "given_name",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false,
                        "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                            "MinLength": "0",
                            "MaxLength": "2048"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "family_name",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false,
                        "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                            "MinLength": "0",
                            "MaxLength": "2048"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "middle_name",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false,
                        "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                            "MinLength": "0",
                            "MaxLength": "2048"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "nickname",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false,
                        "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                            "MinLength": "0",
                            "MaxLength": "2048"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "preferred_username",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false,
                        "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                            "MinLength": "0",
                            "MaxLength": "2048"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "profile",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false,
                        "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                            "MinLength": "0",
                            "MaxLength": "2048"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "picture",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false,
                        "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                            "MinLength": "0",
                            "MaxLength": "2048"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "website",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false,
                        "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                            "MinLength": "0",
                            "MaxLength": "2048"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "email",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": true,
                        "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                            "MinLength": "0",
                            "MaxLength": "2048"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "email_verified",
                        "AttributeDataType": "Boolean",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "gender",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false,
                        "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                            "MinLength": "0",
                            "MaxLength": "2048"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "birthdate",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false,
                        "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                            "MinLength": "10",
                            "MaxLength": "10"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "zoneinfo",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false,
                        "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                            "MinLength": "0",
                            "MaxLength": "2048"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "locale",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false,
                        "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                            "MinLength": "0",
                            "MaxLength": "2048"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "phone_number",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false,
                        "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                            "MinLength": "0",
                            "MaxLength": "2048"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "phone_number_verified",
                        "AttributeDataType": "Boolean",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "address",
                        "AttributeDataType": "String",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false,
                        "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                            "MinLength": "0",
                            "MaxLength": "2048"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "updated_at",
                        "AttributeDataType": "Number",
                        "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                        "Mutable": true,
                        "Required": false,
                        "NumberAttributeConstraints": {
                            "MinValue": "0"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "LambdaConfig": {},
                "AutoVerifiedAttributes": [
                    "email"
                ],
                "UsernameAttributes": [
                    "email"
                ],
                "SmsVerificationMessage": "Your verification code is {####}. ",
                "EmailVerificationMessage": "Your app verification code is {####}. ",
                "EmailVerificationSubject": "Your app verification code",
                "SmsAuthenticationMessage": "Your authentication code is {####}. ",
                "MfaConfiguration": "OFF",
                "EmailConfiguration": {},
                "UserPoolTags": {},
                "AdminCreateUserConfig": {
                    "AllowAdminCreateUserOnly": false,
                    "UnusedAccountValidityDays": 7,
                    "InviteMessageTemplate": {
                        "SMSMessage": "Your username is {username} and temporary password is {####}. ",
                        "EmailMessage": "Your username is {username} and temporary password is {####}. ",
                        "EmailSubject": "Your temporary password"
                    }
                }         
            }
        }          
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "CognitoUserPoolARN": {
            "Value": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "CognitoUserPool",
                    "Arn"
                ]
            },
            "Export": {
                "Name": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-cognito-userpool-arn"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `"Schema"` is the output of a **current and working** User Pool:

```sh
aws cognito-idp describe-user-pool --user-pool-id POOL_ID
```

I have this error when creating the stack (with a different name of course), even though the stack is valid:

> 1 validation error detected: Value 'phone_number_verified' at 'schema.18.member.name' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 20 (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: ID)

The `phone_number_verified` is Boolean.

Comment: For me it was an error for `Failed to call putEvents in Personalize` `'eventList' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 10`. I was sending too many items, apparently the max number of events was 10 to be sent at the same time

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue was: **The Name: "phone_number_verified" is too long (over 20 chars).** Changing it to something like "phonenumber_verified" will work.

[image]

**Note**: the command `aws cloudformation validate-template` won't catch this.

Answer (score 2):

The error i got is this,

```
1 validation error detected: Value 'custom:cognitoIdentityId' at 
'schema.3.member.name' failed to satisfy constraint: .
Member must have length less than or equal to 20 
(Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; 
Error Code: InvalidParameterException; 
Request ID: 2c7c69a9-68ca-4ccc-a951-ab3fa0be2689)
```

According to this, the "name" attribute is too long. The value of the name attribute is "custom:cognitoIdentityId".

According to the documentation, Minimum: 1 and Maximum: 20.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-schemaattribute.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-schemaattribute-name

Answer (score 1):

The hint is in the error message but I agree it is terribly misleading.
It does not mention which `Member` it is referring to. For this api, it's the `Schema` property that you have above.

You will notice that you have 21 attributes under `Schema`. Since the API accepts at most 20 **at a time**, you could remove any one of the attributes and try again.
I think that once you create with the 20 resources, you should be able to add it back.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've checked again and in the template, there are 20 attributes under Schema. If I remove the `phone_number_verified` object, the stack is created normally without errors.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it is. If you edit it, then I will.

Comment: what's missing? I mentioned removed any one of them should do it and you removed `phone_number_verified`, so that does the trick, correct?

Comment: I have only 20 attributes, not 21, and that's the core of your answer. So technically, your answer is not correct.
The error I had was about the `phone_number_verified` and for some reason (not because of the number of attributes, removing it solved my problem, but if I removed another attribute, I still had the error.

Comment: I don't think this error is because of the number of attributes, rather the length of the attributes name. Note that Cognito will always prefix `custom:` with your attribute names and will count the length including the prefix.

Comment: good point, Annjawn. My answer worked for me but it's possible that you people are facing another edge case

Comment: This answer is wrong. As the error shows -  `phone_number_verified` is 18th attribute. The problem is with the length of the name - it's 21 characters long. @Viet answer below is the correct.

Comment: @iaforek. Thank you for the notice. I've forgotten this question.